# How to invert axis of a pillow image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, python-imaging-library, seaborn

Seaborn offers the possibility to invert the axis of an image. I would like to do the same with PIL. Here is my code.

```
# Imports
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
from PIL import Image
import random

# Arrays
r = []
g = []
b = []
for i in range(200):
    r.append(random.sample(range(0, 255), 200))
    g.append(random.sample(range(0, 255), 200))
    b.append(random.sample(range(0, 255), 200))
    
# Change color of the left part of the image
r = np.array(r)
r[:, 0:10]=0

# Change color of the right part of the image
r = np.array(r)
r[:, -10:-1]=150

g = np.array(g)
g[:, -10:-1]=150


# Plot seaborn heatmap
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sax = sns.heatmap(r)
sax.invert_xaxis()
```

[image: original im]

`sax.invert_xaxis()` inverts the x-axis of the plot.

[image: inverse img]

I would like to do the same with pillow. I have been google it for a long time without finding anything.
Here is my rgb pillow image.

```
rgbarr = np.zeros((200,200,3), 'uint8')
rgbarr[..., 0] = np.array(r)
rgbarr[..., 1] = np.array(g)
rgbarr[..., 2] = np.array(b)
img = Image.fromarray(rgbarr)
img
```

[image: PIL img]

opencv possibility would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want to flip it:

```
 im_flipped = im.transpose(method=Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark Setchell. The word 'just' is in the right place.